# Web crawler class

Tags: python, object-oriented

I'm using my crawler class in the following manner and I'm beginning to think it's bad practice:

**crawler.py**

```
import requests

class Crawler():
    def __init__(self, url):
        self.url = url

    def web_crawler(self):
        requests.get(self.url)
        return requests.text
```

**main.py**

```
for url in urls:
    crawler = Crawler(url)
    results = crawler.web_crawler()
```

Would it be better to move the `url` parameter outside of `Crawler`'s `__init__` and move it into the `web_crawler` function? That way the class won't have to be reinitialized multiple times in main.py.

Comment: `return requests.text`? Did you, at least, tried to run this code?

Answer (score 5):

As the `Crawler` class just has one method along with `__init__`, you can avoid a class altogether and write:

```
def web_crawler(url):
    requests.get(url)
    return requests.text
```

You now have to initialize exactly 0 times, thus removing the problem from the root:

```
for url in urls:
    results = web_crawler(url)
```

The code is also simplified, both in definition and usage.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create a field name url, and use getter and setter to obtain/change the value outside of the class.

Comment: This may be the start of a good review, but in it's current form it doesn't provide much value. Would you care to expand a bit?

Comment: Would've been a good idea but I don't think it's a good practice. This reminds me of Java.

Comment: Well I just noted that you can take the variable out and provide mechanism for changing it, this way you will need to change a variable only. Also I must note that you may have problems with multi threading if it isn't implemented properly.